# XmlGregorianCalendar create date with System timezone

Tags: java, date

I am creating a series of dates to store in my database as a JSON string and they're all being saved as GMT (`2015-05-01T13:00:00.000Z`, for instance). My computer is on GMT+2, so when I try to display them I get 2 hours added to my dates.

How can I force `XmlGregorianCalendar` to create a `Date` object using the system's timezone?

Comment: please post the minimal code to reproduce the problem

Comment: By default `XmlGregorianCalendar` takes system's time zone. What are you expecting here?

Answer (score 0):

By Default it takes System's Time Zone. If You want to use Some Other Time Zone you can Do this 
either by passing it to the constructor or by setting it afterwards. So both of the line will work

```
 GregorianCalendar gcInstance = new GregorianCalendar(YOUR_TIME_ZONE);
gcInstance.setTimeZone(YOUR_TIME_ZONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like when you are saving the Date, it's not getting the correct timezone.

Are both applications running in the same machine?

If not, the machine that saves the object should get date as:

```
Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT+2"));
```

***Tip: Sometime ago I struggle with this kind of GMT problem. At the end, I just converted the fields to `Strings`. (I'm not proud of this, though).***